# How to log condition in the exim?

Tags: logging, configuration, exim

I want to see value of condition in exim, for example "authenticated". I can use authenticated = *, but I don't know what really contains "authenticated".

If I add section warn with parameter `logwrite = $authenticated` I get error `unknown variable name "authenticated"`.

Also I want to see what contains in the condition "spam". There's many manuals say just add `spam = nobody:false`, but I can't understand who is nobody and what is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated connections show up in the protocol field.  This is found on the lines recording the sender (indicated by `<=` after the id.  The protocols that indicate an authenticated messsage are `esmtpsa`, `smtpsa`, `esmtpa` and `smtpa`.  `estmp` indicates extended SMTP requested by using the `EHLO` command instead of the `HELO` command.  The `sa` suffix indicates authentication on a secure (TLS) connection, as compared to `s` (unauthenticated TLS) or `a` (authenticated on unsecured channel). The authentication details follow `A=` on the same line.

```
1bZnEj-0007DV-QV <= me@example.com H=host.lan.example.com [192.0.2.47] P=esmtpsa A=dovecot_plain:me S=760 id=3BCA15E6-988F-4908-8605-D87E773A0886@example.com
```

This `warn` clause will cause the configured spam filter to be run and spam report logged in the Exim log.  Spamassassin will already be logging this data to the maillog, so I would remove the logwrite message as soon as you are happy it is working.

```
# Add a spam flag
warn
  spam = mail:true
  logwrite = $spam_report
```

See the [Content Scanning](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-content_scanning_at_acl_time.html#SECTscanspamass) chapter of the Exim Specification for more information on spam scanning.  Get to know your way around the specification document.